# USA: What is a code compliant method of running 12/2 through wood ledger board and into outside junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image][image]I need to run one circuit of 12/2 from the basement (ranch house) up to the attic and then outside via the ledger board of the roof over my deck. Should I screw a short nipple into the back of the junction box (outdoor rated) and feed the wire through that so when I attach it to the board the nipple goes into the attic and the 12/2 cable is not exposed in any way to the outside? The junction box I have has little knobs on the back so when it is screwed to the ledger board there would be a small 1/8" gap all the way around. I'm at work currently but I will take some pics of the area in question and add them.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - your title mentions "through concrete" but your text doesn't. Will the run go through concrete? If so, is there conduit in place or are you drilling a fresh hole? Does concrete have nothing to do with it? If not, [edit] your post to remove that reference from the title question. Side note: Keep in mind that working in the eve will be _very_ difficult unless this is at the gable end or you've got a gambrel roof!

Comment: Oh wow!!!!! I am trying to determine which way I want to run the wire so I guess my brain and my fingers were acting independently!!!!! I edited my question. Thanks for the heads up FreeMan. I've already ran some speaker wire and security camera wire through the soffit so you are correct there is little to no room to work with and I usually end up with a face full of pink insulation!!!!!!

Comment: Sounds like a "dry" location anyway. It's under the roof, right? You may not need any special fixings or cable.

Comment: When you go outside you have to change from normal 12/2 nmb to another method Like UF even in conduit because conduit outside is defined as a wet location so nmb can not be used, it depends on the location what else may be required above 8’ you can even run most UF fully exposed if it is listed sunlight or UV resistant. (If you live in Oregon there is a state wide exception that allows for vertical runs of nmb in conduit up to 8’ ). Once we have the photo we will be able to be more precise.

Comment: I've got non-metallic liquid tight conduit and THHN wire to change over to once outside and spliced into the junction box

Comment: Yes isherwood everything is under the roof over my deck

Comment: Are you running NM or UF here?

Comment: 12/2 NM from panel then through deck roof ledger board below soffit and into junction box.Then the NM will be pigtailed to THHN inside liquid tight conduit.